# Passing class items as arguments

Tags: python, class

I am working on a script, and could use some guidance. The purpose of the script is to allow players to get magic items and store them in a specific slot. I am having the issue of trying to generate an item based on what slot is given.

I am creating a child-class of type dict. This is where I will be storing the users' items.

```
class PlayerData(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self.weapon = 0
        self.head = 0
        self.back = 0
        self.chest = 0
        self.hands = 0
        self.feet = 0

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self.__getitem__(attr)

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        self.__setitem__(attr, value)
```

I store these values in a dictionary. I have a class which modifies these entries. One of the methods iterates over the items in PlayerData and if all items are empty, grabs a random one and attempts to add an object (of type MagicItem) to it. "self.steamid" is the reference to a player.

```
def addItem(self):
    chance = 75
    slot = 0
    count = 0
    for k,v in PlayerDataDictionary[self.steamid].iteritems():
        if not v:
            count += 1
    if count = 6:
        chance = 100
    if random.randint(1,100) <= chance:
        slot = random.choice(PlayerDataDictionary[self.steamid])
        if slot:
            chooseReplace(self, slot)
        else:
            PlayerDataDictionary[self.steamid][slot] = MagicItem(slot)
    else:
        es.tell(userid, '#green', 'You destroyed your item during creation!')
        # This is a custom module for a game, this function works as intended
```

However, which item that is created depends on the slot. How would I determine which slot from PlayerData was passed to the class MagicItem?

Comment: `if count = 6:`... Does this compile?

Comment: What advantage do you gain by using your `PlayerData` class over using a plain dictionary or a plain class with its attributes?

Comment: I haven't compiled yet, still working out how I want it to run. I am using it as a class in case I need to add some methods, and as of right now does it not use a dictionary's attributes?

Answer (score 1):

From the way I understand what's going on, the line:

```
slot = random.choice(PlayerDataDictionary[self.steamid])
```

is the only place that `slot` is ever assigned. Therefore, you should be able to just pass that variable somewhere (print, another function, whatever you want to do with it). If you're looking for the specific index, then you're going to either need to write a function in `PlayerDataDictionary` that can return the index of the slot or:

```
size = len(PlayerDataDictionary[self.steamid])
random_slot = random.randint(0, size)
```

Which will leave `random_slot` with an index value which you can then pass

```
if PlayerDataDictionary[self.steamid][random_slot]:
    chooseReplace(self, random_slot)
else:
    PlayerDataDictionary[self.steamid][random_slot] = MagicItem(random_slot)
```

This should work so long as I understand your problem correctly. You left some abiguity as to what exactly you were looking for, so let me know if I missed the exact question.

Comment: @C1pher How would I go about getting a specific index? Would I just iterate over the keys in PlayerData or would there be a more efficient way?

Comment: You can't get a specific index out of the dictionary as you would expect from a list, I just assumed that your slots were numbered as such in the dictionary. You can iterate over either `dict.keys()` or `dict.values()` where `dict` is the name of your dictionary.